# Make always runs for target "all", even when there's nothing to update

Tags: c++, makefile

I have these files

- Test.cpp
- Point.h
- Point.cpp
- Triangle.h
- Triangle.cpp

and I want to have a makefile that allows me to build each of the classes `Point` and `Triangle` separately by issuing `make Point` or `make Triangle` when needed (either the header or source files have changed). `make all` should compile everything and build the output program `Test` if needed.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
OBJS=Test.o Point.o Triangle.o

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o Test


Point.o : Point.cpp Point.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c Point.cpp

Point : Point.o


Triangle.o : Triangle.h Triangle.cpp Point.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c Triangle.cpp

Triangle : Triangle.o


clean:
    \rm *.o Test


.PHONY : Point Triangle
```

It seems to work, but the problem is that when i run `make all` (or just `make`) multiple times it runs the command even if nothing has changed, giving the following output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic Test.o Point.o Triangle.o -o Test
```

I want it to say something like "Nothing to be done for 'all'." or something similar, just like it does for the other targets. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all` knows nothing about the output file `Test`. Since it doesn't know about any specific target file, it can't compare the timestamp of target and dependencies. That's why it's always running the command. You need to tell make that by `all` you actually meant to generate the file `Test`. You can do something like this:

```
all : Test

Test : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o Test
```

Apart from this issue you also need to specify rule for `Test.o`.

Comment: His "all" depends on "Test.o Point.o Triangle.o". Once those are created, shouldn't the repeated builds just skip the process?

Comment: @blackpen no it doesn't work that way. `all` is not a real target, it doesn't have an actual file whose timestamp can be compared.

Comment: yes, ofcourse. "all" is non-existent, thus it's timestamp is also non-existent. So, it re-fires.

Answer (score 5):

Guessing behaviour of **make** will waste a lot of precious time for you. I have seen people spending hours/days in endless cycles of rebuilds, with each make coming out with different results.

Here is the good news. Almost every **make** tool has a "explain" feature (gnu's make uses **--debug**) using which you can pinpoint the reasons for a rebuild.

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip. I've just spent way more time than I am willing to admit trying all sorts of command line options hoping one of them would do exactly what `--debug` does

Comment: @blackpen you are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule defined for `Test.o`.

Comment: Shouldn't the built-in rule that checks to see that Test.o is newer than Test.cpp be enough for that?