# cmake C++ project builds all files without code change

Tags: cmake, libraries

We have a large CMake managed C++ project. The project has a lot of dependencies which we manage via CMake external projects.

I'm refactoring the CMake-part of our code which handles the external projects.

When I delete the executable, the whole code is rebuilt (same in time, but not the order for a clean build). In the original code this is not the case and also with my current branch, when I use ninja instead of make.

In theory my refactoring shall have no effect at all, I'm just changing how the external projects are built. The only thing which has impact on the code are slight modifications of the order of libs from the external projects. I only changed a few of the external projects.

I need to do git bisection to identify the issue, but I currently have no idea what could have made the issue. Note that it works with ninja.

Comment: Without the code we cannot point you to the reason of the rebuild. But you could ask you build tool for explanations why it rebuilds files. In case of Make, you could run `make --debug`, as described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39345851/3440745),

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about this.

This gives me a hint to solve the problem!

I got an endless list of each external header in the include file of kind

"Prerequisite `include/<deps_include>' is newer than target `source/<own code>'"

And indeed the dependency files are touched at make. 

I suspect it has something to do with cmake policy CMP0135 which is about the DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP policy of external projects.

Comment: My guess with CMP0135 was not correct, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:
With the external projects I have an add_custom_command() with

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory <source> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
```

And this touched all `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib`

This does not happen replacing `copy_directory` by `copy_if_different`. In my case I'm not happy with `copy_if_different` and need to change more but at least I identified the cause for everything being rebuilt.